# How to get Average Visualization Time of an asset in Azure Media Services v3

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-media-services

im currently working in a module of analysis of stadistics of videos from azure media services. I want to ask how can i get some data like average visualization time, number of visualizations and more stuff like that. im pretty sure it has to exist a very easy way to get this data but i cannot find it. I found that application insights could be useful. I have found that i may have to manually track this information. Im working on .net6. An example of code would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

pd: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-javascript-azure-media-player-application-insights-plugin/blob/master/options.md
I have found that Application Insights could be useful to my problem. Some classes like TelemetryClient (from the package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights) seems to be useful to my problem, but i cant find clear information about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no concept of client side analytics or viewer analytics in Azure Media Services.  You have to track and log things on your own on the client side.  App Insights is a good solution for this, and there are some older samples out there showing how to do that with a player application.

Take a look at this sample - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/media-services-javascript-azure-media-player-application-insights-plugin/media-services-javascript-azure-media-player-application-insights-plugin/

Just WARNING: it is very old and probably very out of date. I would not use much of the code from that sample, as it is using SDK's from 4 year ago. Just use it as guidance at a high level for what the architecture might look like.

Another solution would be to look to a 3rd party service like Mux.com/Data that can plug into any player framework for client analytics.

Comment: Thx u very much for the answer John. Will it be the same case if im looking for the number of visualizations? or azure Media Player has some funcinality related to this?.
I will try to use that plugin or at least something similar to it. But i have another question, should i use the class TelemetryClient to extract the data from this application insights plugin? Im working in a net 6 project on c# if it is useful. Thx in advance!